# pretty printing sympy array

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to create 2-dim arrays in sympy but getting error. Here is my code:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.tensor.array import Array

init_printing()
x = symbols('x')
vec1 = Array([ [x,x**2],[x**3,x**4]  ])
print(vec1)
```

I am getting output as

```
[[x, x**2], [x**3, x**4]]
```

But I wanted to get output as pretty printed array like shown on http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/printing.html. How can I do that? 
I am using python 3.6 running on Spyder 3.4 on Windows.

Comment: I think `**` is power. If it is so, then it is printing as per the documentation

Answer (score 1):

Install [jupyter](http://jupyter.org/) and latex

```
pip3 install jupyter
pip install jupyter_latex_envs
```

Then call qtconsole:

```
jypyter qtconsole
```

And type the code:

[image: Jupyter qtconsole]

See the code in [this jupyter notebook.](https://anaconda.org/sidon/prettyprint-sympy/notebook)